# Comparing Equivalent Fractions

Tags: fractions

could I compare two fractions with proportional or not proportional sizes two fractions that are to be compared aren't equivalent to each other it's a pre-algebra question any answer you will give will help me reach the right answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: It is not very clear what are you asking, so maybe this quecton will be closed soon. I can tell that fractions $a/b$ and $c/d$ of integer (or even real) numbers with non-zero $b$ and $d$ can be compared. Namely $a/b\le c/d$ iff $c/d-a/b\ge 0$. If both $b$ and $d$ are positive, this holds if and only if $ad\le bc$.